# node express mysql driver insert action error

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express

I try to code rest API using express and mysql but i have problem with inserting data to database

```
router.route('/todo')
.post(function(req, res){
    if(connection){
        var obj = {
            task: req.body.task, 
            date: Date()
        }
        connection.query('insert into task set ?', obj , function(err, info){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('dodano z id:' + info.insertId);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    }
})
.get(function(req, res){
    if(connection) {
        connection.query('select * from task order by id', function(err, rows){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(rows);
            res.end;
        });
    }
});
```

I use a simple firefox plugin for restfull api and when i send Post method {"task":"one"} i get this error on console: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'task' cannot be null.

What i do wrong?

Comment: What does `console.dir(req.body.task);` output in your POST handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening is that your `req.body` is not being populated, perhaps due to a missing or misconfigured appropriate body handling middleware. The reasoning behind this is that the [`mysql` module treats both javascript `undefined` and `null` values as the mysql `null` value](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/1d4cb893a9906890554016c398dccb4271e66808/lib/protocol/SqlString.js#L17-L19). So if `req.body` is not being populated, that means `req.body.task === undefined` which means the mysql `null` value will be used by the `mysql` module. This causes the error you're seeing because `null` is not permitted for your task column.

So you need to make sure that:

- You are using some sort of json body parsing middleware somewhere before that route. So for example [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) has a json body parser that you can `use()` via `bodyParser.json()`.
- Your request is sending the proper `Content-Type` header, for example: `Content-Type: application/json` (a `charset` parameter can optionally be added to the `Content-Type` header value).